# is HAVING clause before GROUP BY clause processed differently than after?

Tags: query-performance, execution-plan

**Is there any difference how query is processed (translated to extended relational algebra), if HAVING condition is written before GROUP BY (compared to after)?**
In logical query plan it should be initially upper in the tree (after GROUP BY) ? As far as I understand the topic(having selection should execute later in any case)? Is that correct?

I was translating some sql query to logical query plan  (extended relational algebra) and in the query HAVING was before GROUP BY, which I thought might be incorrect, but on google I found it might be possible  in some implementations.

Comment: You can't write HAVING clause before GROUP BY clause, unless you have it in a subquery.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. This resource https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019174/how-to-make-sure-having-happens-before-group-by/7019238 confused me a bit.

Comment: If I get query like that in exam, I'll just say that conversion to extended relational algebra results with parsing error.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ maybe it depends on RDBMS, there's none tagged here, but some do support it, in which case it makes no difference on which order you put it.

Comment: @AndrewSayer I don't know of any that supports this but there are so many, there might be some that do - as an extention/deviation from the standard.

Comment: According to https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/ having and group by cant change place in an SQL query. Since the semantics is undefined I guess one must check the docs for any DBMS that allows this.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ it works in Oracle just fine with no different behaviour https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ea7f18309d5af0ae238b8ba60ae4a922 it might be the only one but it's definitely a widely used system (that isn't to say you would normally write the SQL with `having` first but it works). @Lennart Mimer is it's own RDBMS, something not being accepted in its beta validation form from 2016 is not really an indication of any working behaviour for any other RDBMS.

Comment: Im not claiming that it is describing any working behaviour. The tool is supposed to validate sql against the sql standard. Assuming the validator does its job, it is not valid to switch the two. In such case the semantics of the construct needs to be defined by the vendor

Comment: @AndrewSayer thnx for the example, I didn't know that worked in Oracle.

Comment: I see it in Oracle's docs as well: *"Specify GROUP BY and HAVING after the where_clause and hierarchical_query_clause. **If you specify both GROUP BY and HAVING, then they can appear in either order.**"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference.

The aggregation within the `having` clause will always use the grouping specified by the `group by`.